# platonic solids in 4D

Tags: geometry, 3d

I've noticed in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-dimensional_space) that each 4D figure is constructed of [3D platonic solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid) to get to these, just like using [polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon) on solids. In the hypercube, you have the cube in the center and the cube on the outside. The cube rotates oddly, allowing there to be 4 positions with this. and then using simple math, you get $4\times 2=8$, and there are 8 cubes in a hypercube net, seen at the aforementioned first link.

But there is something off: I can't see how the 3D animations of the 5-cell, 120-cell, and 600-cell rotate so i cannot distinguish the 5 or 120 or 600 figures. Is there another way (besides the nets) to tell that the 600-cell has 600 tetrahedron?

Comment: Coding? Such as gif or animation

Comment: The $600$-cell has $600$ tetrahedron facets, not $600$ icosahedra.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke oh. changing it...

Comment: "is there another way (...) to tell": Could you rephrase your question. What do you mean by a way to tell?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke done.